# Did Boba Fett survive the Sarlacc encounter?

Tags: star-wars, boba-fett

In Extended Universe aka Legends continuity, it is established that after being thrown to the pit, Boba Fett survived Sarlacc due to his extremely strong armor.

Is this true for the current Star Wars canon?

Comment: [Yes, it's canon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RQUPUFRgro).

Comment: ^ funny, but for anyone that stubmles upon this, that comment is a joke :)